# how to approach leaf variables to freeze weight parameters

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, quantization

i want to fix weights which have a value of 'zero' in model.parameters() (model is a neural network)
it means i have to freeze it in element-wise so i made a code below.

in the code, model.parameters() will be input of 'Lparam'
and when i ran the code, i got an error like 'nonetype has no attribute 'zero_()'

and when i try another trick like `requires_grad=False`, error says like,
"only leaf variables can use `requires_grad`"

then how can i approach leaf variables to fix the zero weights in the computation graph?
here is my code.

```
def fix_tensor_data(Lparam):
    if isinstance(Lparam,type(None)):
        return
    
    elif torch.is_tensor(Lparam):  
        if Lparam.dim() == 0 and Lparam == 0:
            Lparam.grad.zero_()
        elif Lparam.dim() == 0 and Lparam != 0:
            return
        else:
            for tp1 in Lparam:
                fix_tensor_data(tp1)
                
    else: #enter this section only once when Lparam is a generator
        for tp2 in Lparam:
                fix_tensor_data(tp2)
```